# Combining property values from duplicates in list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was curious as to the best way to combine properties from duplicate records in a list. For example:

```
 var res = new List<MyObjList> {
     new MyObj { Id = 1, Type = "Class", Current = "Math", New = "Science" },
     new MyObj { Id = 2, Type = "Class", Current = "Math", New = "Science" },
     new MyObj { Id = 1, Type = "Year", Current = "Freshman", New = "Sophomore" },
     new MyObj { Id = 3, Type = "Year", Current = "Junior", New = "Senior" }                         
 }
```

I'm looking for this result:

```
 var res = new List<NewObj> {
     new NewObj { Id = 1, Class = "Math", UpcomingYear = "Freshman" },
     new NewObj { Id = 2, Class = "Math", UpcomingYear = null },
     new NewObj { Id = 3, Class = null, UpcomingYear = "Senior" }                        
 }
```

Failed attempt:

```
 var newRes = res
      .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
      .Select(grp => new NewObj {
            ItemId = grp.Key.Id,
            Class = grp.Key.Type == "Class" ? grp.Key.Class : null,
            UpcomingYear = grp.Key.Type == "Year" ? grp.Key.UpcomingYear : null
});
```

The thing I don't quite understand is how to join duplicates by ID and create a new object with conditional property values (or combine properties from each duplicate).

Edit: Updated result type/object

Edit2: Updated with failed attempts

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the results in json? if so specifically add that to the question

Comment: New object would be preferred. Updated question with new output example

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do some _research_. Try _something_. You will probably want to start with LINQ's `group by` syntax.

Comment: I didn't think it was worth adding failed attempts, but I've done research. I added an example of an attempt if that helps find a solution.

Comment: You have two objects with `Id = 1`. But they have different values in `Type` and `Current` properties. As a result you want to take `Class` from one object and `Current` from other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
const string ClassType = "Class";
const string YearType = "Year";
var newRes = res
    .Where(r => r.Type == ClassType)
    .Select(r => new
    {
        r.Id,
        Class = r.Current,
        UpcomingYear = res
            .Where(r2 => r2.Id == r.Id && r2.Type == YearType)
            .Select(r2 => r2.Current)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Union(res
        .Where(r =>
            r.Type != ClassType &&
            !res.Any(r2 => r2.Id == r.Id && r2.Type == ClassType))
        .Select(r => new
        {
            r.Id,
            Class = default(string),
            UpcomingYear = r.New
        }));

foreach(var item in newRes)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id}, '{item.Class}', '{item.UpcomingYear}'");
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 1, 'Math', 'Freshman' 
 2, 'Math', '' 
 3, '', 'Senior'
```

Comment: Yup, this was exactly what I needed and it makes much more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `Person` class with 2 properties: `FirstName` and `LastName`.

And you have a list of people, you want to combine those who have the same `FirstName` and `LastName` (i.e. remove duplicates).

You could use LINQ's `GroupBy` method, like the following example:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
    new Person 
    {
        FirstName = "Arad",
        LastName = "Aral"
    },
    new Person
    {
        FirstName = "Arad",
        LastName = "Aral"
    }
};

List<Person> duplicatesRemoved = people.GroupBy(p => p.FirstName + p.LastName).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Now, our new list `duplicatesRemoved` is as follows:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
    new Person 
    {
        FirstName = "Arad",
        LastName = "Aral"
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I'm familiar with GroupBy, the thing that's throwing me off is combining two different properties into one object IF that property has a value. For example, say the second person object had a middle name and I want the result to be a combination of FirstName/LastName(if LastName exists) and FirstName/MiddleName (if MiddleName exists)

Comment: @Josh Tell me if I misunderstood you: say we have another property in the `Person` class in this example called `MiddleName` and we also have an `Id`, both the persons' ids are the same (so they are duplicate and should be combined), the second person in the list has a `MiddleName` but the first one doesn't, if the scenario is correct so far, what do you want the final list to have? One person with the first name and last name of the first person and the middle name of the second? It's a little hard to understand your scenario exactly.